# FFMPEG fails to trim beginning of clip

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have two `.MTS` files taken in sequence and I want to trim them to the first five seconds. This command works for the first file:

```sh
ffmpeg -ss 0 -to 5 -i 00117.MTS -vcodec copy -acodec copy start_00117.MTS
```

The result is 5 seconds and 17 MB, as opposed to the 12 minutes and 2 GB from the original.

The same command on the second file fails:

```sh
ffmpeg -ss 0 -to 5 -i 00118.MTS -vcodec copy -acodec copy start_00118.MTS
```

The result is 12 minutes and 2 GB, like its original file.

What is the problem?

**Full log**:

```
$ rm start_00117.MTS; ffmpeg -ss 0 -to 5 -i 00117.MTS -vcodec copy -acodec copy start_00117.MTS
ffmpeg version 4.1.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1.4_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags='-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin' --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-libaom --enable-libsoxr
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, mpegts, from '00117.MTS':
  Duration: 00:12:36.02, start: 1.040000, bitrate: 22490 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Stream #0:0[0x1011]: Video: h264 (High) (HDMV / 0x564D4448), yuv420p(top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1100]: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x1200]: Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle ([144][0][0][0] / 0x0090), 1920x1080
Output #0, mpegts, to 'start_00117.MTS':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (HDMV / 0x564D4448), yuv420p(top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  304 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=   16601kB time=00:00:06.02 bitrate=22590.4kbits/s speed=25.8x    
video:15162kB audio:189kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 8.143849%
$ rm start_00118.MTS; ffmpeg -ss 0 -to 5 -i 00118.MTS -vcodec copy -acodec copy start_00118.MTS
rm: start_00118.MTS: No such file or directory
ffmpeg version 4.1.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1.4_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags='-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin' --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-libaom --enable-libsoxr
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, mpegts, from '00118.MTS':
  Duration: 00:12:36.59, start: 756.592000, bitrate: 22471 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Stream #0:0[0x1011]: Video: h264 (High) (HDMV / 0x564D4448), yuv420p(top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1100]: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x1200]: Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle ([144][0][0][0] / 0x0090), 1920x1080
Output #0, mpegts, to 'start_00118.MTS':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (HDMV / 0x564D4448), yuv420p(top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=37804 fps=923 q=-1.0 Lsize= 2130467kB time=00:12:36.54 bitrate=23069.0kbits/s speed=18.5x    
video:1946718kB audio:23627kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 8.126621%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be a bug with input `-to`. For now, use `-ss` and `-to` as output options.

```
ffmpeg -i 00118.MTS -ss 0 -to 5 -c copy start_00118.MTS
```

Comment: This fixed it. Shall I report it as a bug to the developers? What details of the input file should I include?

Comment: You can file a report at trac.ffmpeg.org. Upgrade to git master and share full commands and logs for both files.

Comment: By "upgrade to git master", do you mean download the source code and compile locally?

Comment: Use the binary in https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/macos64/static/ffmpeg-20190812-faa9cd3-macos64-static.zip

Comment: I filed a bug report at https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8189#ticket

Comment: The conclusion of the bug report was that this is not a bug but a case where stream copy fails. I added an answer.

Comment: Bug ticket should not have been closed. I've reopened it. Please re-up the samples.

Comment: I have re-uploaded the samples and updated the ticket. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using `-c copy` may fail in several situations and this is one of them. From the [documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy):

> Stream copy is a mode selected by supplying the `copy` parameter to the `-codec` option. It makes ffmpeg omit the decoding and encoding step for the specified stream, so it does only demuxing and muxing. It is useful for changing the container format or modifying container-level metadata. The diagram above will, in this case, simplify to this:
>
> ```
>  _______              ______________            ________
> |       |            |              |          |        |
> | input |  demuxer   | encoded data |  muxer   | output |
> | file  | ---------> | packets      | -------> | file   |
> |_______|            |______________|          |________|
> ```
>
> Since there is no decoding or encoding, it is very fast and there is no quality loss. However, it might not work in some cases because of many factors.

This is one such factor. See [the closed bug report](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8189) for a longer explanation and the coincidence of why the command works with the first section of a long record and not the second section.

Removing `-c copy` (or `-vcodec copy -acodec copy`) fixes the corner case, i.e.:

```sh
ffmpeg -ss 0 -to 5 -i 00122.MTS start_00122.MTS
```

See also Gyan's solution of using `-ss` and `-to` as output options, which also fixes the corner case.